# How to mock values in Config.groovy in Grails for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, mocking

I want to write some test cases where I have to mock some properties of the config file.

Below shown is the actual code

```
if (password.length() < grailsApplication.config.user.password.min.length) {
    return false
}
```

I want to mock `grailsApplication.config.user.password.min.length`
In my config file, `user.password.min.length` has been set as `6`

I tried to mock in the following ways:

1. `mockConfig = new ConfigObject()`
       `mockConfig.user.password.min.length = 6`
2. `mockConfig("user.password.min.length")`
3. `mockConfig(user.password.min.length)`
4. `mockConfig(mockConfig.user.password.min.length)`

But none of this is working. My code is throwing `NullPointerException` sometimes. 
Could someone please advise the correct way to mock the config file?

Comment: One way would be to simply mock `grailsApplication` and let it return `config = [ user: [ password : [ min : [ length : x ] ] ] ]` - that's how I usually do it, haven't had much luck with `mockConfig` for some reason :(

Comment: How to mock grailsApplication? GrailsApplication is an interface. Could you please tell the code to mock and returning the config as explained above?

Comment: Well what testing tools are you using? In Spock I do `service.grailsApplication = Stub(GrailsApplication) {
   getConfig() >> [ key1 : [ key2 : [ key3 : value ] ] ]
  }`

Comment: i am using JUnit in STS

Comment: You could try [this](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Developer+Testing+using+Closures+instead+of+Mocks) approach and end up with something like `service.grailsApplication = [ getConfig : { -> ...construct config object... }] as GrailsApplication`

Comment: protected groovy.util.ConfigObject mockConfig(java.lang.String config) is the syntax for mocking Config object but have not got any luck so far

Comment: answer below is good, please mark as accepted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following is how I mock my config properties in Service spec.

```
@TestFor(MyService)
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {

void "Test case for somemethod" () {
    given:
    grailsApplication.config.my.prop= 'some-prop-value'

    when:
    def result = service.getSomething(keyword)

    then:
    result.label.every {
        it.toLowerCase().contains(keyword)
    }

    where:
    keyword << ["dub", "sing"]
}
```

Note: `my.prop` is the property I'm using inside `getSomething(string)` method.